# Grammatikalische Form von "echter deutscher Honig"?

Tags: adjective, grammatical-case, declension

Mein Honigglas trägt den Schriftzug "echter deutscher Honig".  Welche grammatikalische Form ist das?  Es scheint keiner der üblichen vier Fälle zu sein ("der echte deutsche Honig", "des echten deutschen Honigs" usw.).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Das ist Nominativ, Deklination ohne Artikel. Das Deutsche verfügt über drei Deklinationstabellen für Adjektive: mit dem bestimmten Artikel, mit dem unbestimmten Artikel und mit dem Nullartikel. Das hier ist die Nullartikel-Form.

Warum wurde diese gewählt?

> Der echte deutsche Honig

würde nahelegen, dass es der einzige echte deutsche Honig, was falsch ist.

> Ein echter deutscher Honig

klingt komisch, weil man vor Materialsubstantiven generell kein "ein" verwendet. Die Verwendung von "ein" klingt mehr nach "irgendein", "ein beliebiger", was wohl keine geeignete Werbesprache ist! *(Danke O.R. Mapper für diese Ergänzung)*

Also bleibt die Version ohne Artikel, die eine der drei Deklinationstabellen darstellt. Andere Beispiele für diese Deklination (jedoch nicht mehr im Nominativ):

> aus rostfreie**m** Stahl
>
> Ich trinke gern frische**s** Mineralwasser.

Comment: Kannst du noch allgemein etwas zu starker und schwacher Adjektivflexion ergänzen?

Comment: Schon geschehen.

Comment: Vielleicht sollte man bei den letzten beiden Beispielen noch anmerken, dass es kein Nominativ mehr ist wie zuvor, sondern Dativ und Akkusativ.

Comment: "klingt komisch, weil man vor Materialsubstantiven generell kein "ein" verwendet." - die Erklärung passt eigentlich für beide Fälle. Speziell für den zweiten Fall eignet sich meines Erachtens aber auch die Erklärung, dass "ein ..." so wie "irgendein ...", "ein beliebiger ..." klingt, was dem Alleinstellungswunsch des Herstellers widersprechen dürfte.

Answer (score 6):

Man kann die Aufschrift auch als Ellipse des folgenden Satzes verstehen:

> In diesem Glas befindet sich **echter deutscher Honig**.

Der hervorgehobene Begriff steht also im Nominativ (»**Wer oder was** befindet sich in diesem Glas?«)

Answer (score 2):

Wenn der bestimmte Artikel der/die/das als Genusanzeiger fehlt, übernimmt
das Adjektiv die Anzeige des Genus.